# Laravel Interaction between Session Lifetime, Remember True setting, and Same user/multiple devices

Tags: php, session, cordova, laravel-4

My app uses a Laravel backend for authentication and API.

My problem is that my users get logged out eventually despite the remember true setting when logging in.

Here is my relevant session config:

```
'driver' => 'cookie',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 360,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Login controller:

```
if (Auth::attempt( $credentials, $remember))
        {
            return Response::json('Logged in', 200);
        }
```

Since my users login on both the web app and mobile app simultaneously (Cordova iOS/Android), I'm also wondering if multiple logins by the same user overwrite any session settings (i.e. iOS user logins in with remember true, but web user logins without remember true, overwriting remember true on iOS)